# Excel - Numbering a Priority Column using Sum/Min/Max

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a PRIORITY column I'd like to set up to check against a status column. (Both within a table)

`=IF([@Status]="Complete"` is FALSE, then I'd like to set priority based on highest number currently in the PRIORITY column +1. I'm running into a circular formula, where my progress is pointing to the very cell where I write the formula. I know this is a simple solution that's probably staring right at me.

```
=IF([@Status]="Complete","DONE",SUM(MAX([Priority])+1))
```

Comment: You will need to change the [Priority] to their cell references.  so it would be more like `MAX($A$1:A1)+1` where this would be put in A2.

Comment: You're getting a circular reference because your formula is part of the column it's referring to. Each time it calculates, `MAX([Priority])` will increase by one (and then all of the other instances of that formula will recalculate, and so on...)  I don't think you can do this with a formula which uses a structured table reference like this.